# How format date Carbon:now() in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, formatdatetime

I tried

```
 update(['access' => Carbon::now()->format('Y/m/d H:i:s')]);
```

it returned `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: I find this very helpful: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: What did you want it to return?

Comment: you update this in the database and from the database, you will return only Y-m-d H:i:s

Comment: @RobertColumbia DsRaj I want format 'access' is 'Y/m/d H:i:s', and save it in database. but now it save Y-m-d H:i:s

Comment: The default format in mysql is `Y-m-d H:i:s`, so it will save and show in the same format. If you still want to store it as `Y/m/d H:i:s`, then change data type of date field to varchar.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh I have some row 'access' value null. I can't date_format($member['access'], "Y/m/d H:i:s") in file blade Laravel. Error date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given . How should I do? please help me

Comment: Is the date in the database an actual date type, or is it a string type?

Comment: What's your question after all? Is there anything not working with the given code, or at least not working up to your requirements?

Comment: Reading these comments is like reading 9GAG. It made my day. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 9):

now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')

You Can Format like above code simply.

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php
// ...

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

//...


$now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

The default format in mysql is `Y-m-d H:i:s`, so it will save and show in the same format. If you still want to store it as `Y/m/d H:i:s`, then change data type of date field to varchar.

For issue mentioned in comment:

Create `date object` from string first using [date_create](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp) and then use `date_format` to change its format.

```
$date=date_create($member['access']);
echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

Comment: It OK. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You update this in the database and from the database, you will return only Y-m-d H:i:s(Mysql default format) so

While printing the value of `access`
change the format what you needed.

```
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s',strtotime($member['access']));
```

Comment: Wow, perfect. 

date_format(date_create($member['access']), "Y/m/d H:i:s")

OK too.